# DIV Element Expands Beyond the Visible Portion of Browser

Tags: html, css, position

This problem forks from an earlier issue I was having with getting **DIV elements to expand automatically**, and which was corrected with "overflow: all;".

So with that out of the way, this new issue is almost the complete opposite I guess, this time the DIVS expand beyond the bottom of the page so that a portion of the div is no longer visible. From playing around with the code, this seems only to happen when I position the DIVS relatively.

Please see JSFiddle for a clear example. I have been trying to solve this for hours! Thank you.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wguayan/H6du7/1/)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="block1">
        <div id="one">one</div>
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
        <div id="two">two</div>
        <div id="three">three</div>
        <div id="four">four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />four
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width: 1050px;
margin: auto;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #ededf0;
background: url("http://wguayan.comuv.com/brushed_metal_clear_apple.jpg") repeat;
}
#one, #two, #three, #four {
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
background-color: white;
border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
/* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
}
#one {
float: right;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}
#two {
float: left;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}
#three {
float: right;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 150px;
right: 30px;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}
#four {
float: right;
width: 100px;
position: relative;
top: 300px;
right: 40px;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 9px 9px 12px #888888;
}
#block1 {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
}
#block2 {
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of bad practices going on in your CSS, instead of trying to provide a fixed jsfiddle perhaps a little bit of learning about CSS layouts might do the trick.

So take some time to review please http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: I'm a beginner, I can't really be that hard on myself, but I'm all for learning, so thanks for the link. I'll check that out.

Comment: No problem, there's a mental "ah ha" moment with css layouts and the link should provide you with that moment

Comment: Hey just wanted to say, great material on that link you provided. No "ah ha" moment yet, but good info nonetheless. Positioning and some of the ins and outs of CSS confuse the hell out of me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hate that you're trying so hard to make them float out in space.  It plays a lot of havoc with document flow.

http://jsfiddle.net/H6du7/10/

```
#block2 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Your problem is the "hidden" aspect.   If you make it scroll, or define the height so that it works for you, it'll make your life easier.

Comment: Scrolling is not going to work for the application I plan on using this in. Is there a way to get the container to expand automatically without scrolling?

Comment: Then you've got to play with height values.  Your DIV is being constrained by the parent div  Your problem is most definitely the hidden overflow. If you "show" the overflow then it's going to break out of the bounding container.  I'll tinker a little more with Fiddle, but no promises.

Comment: No pressure, I appreciate you for trying anyway. BTW- Someone else around here suggested I use hidden overflow. It seems to be the only way I can get the DIV holding the gray background to expand automatically, and then I ran into this other problem. I should also mention that assigning a height value fixes the problem temporarily, but those DIVS will hold dynamic content, so they will expand and contract, so a defined height won't work either.

Comment: Ultimately it seems like your background is the bigger problem. I've got the same issue you do, where messing with the height too much causes the background to break.  I don't know what the issue is offhand since I typically prefer solid colors to images.  I'd play around there though, you may be able to remove the "hidden" and size contraints entirely if you can get it to play nice.

Comment: Thanks for trying and for the tips. I guess I'll keep messing with it. As ACE pointed out, I think the real issue is bad CSS practices on my part, which I fully accept and expect. But this one is really stomping me.

Answer (score 0):

The defined position and size of #four cause it to be bigger than its parent. The

```
overflow:hidden
```

css on #block2 is causing the overflow from #four to be hidden.

This is one possible solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/H6du7/9/

Comment: Same problem as the other guy, I can't use scrolling in this application.